# How to mock calls inside a method

Tags: java, mockito

I'm new to Mockito. I want to unit test the following code by calling handle() method with a mocked ClassD parameter:

```
public class ClassA{

    @Autowired
    Bean1 bean1;

    public ClassC handle(ClassD d) {

        ClassC c = bean1.method1(d);
        return methodA(c);
    }
}
```

But I don't want to actually call into method1(). So I wrote the following testcase:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
ClassATest{
@Mock 
ClassD d;
@Mock
Bean1 bean1;

@Mock
ClassC c;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    sut = new ClassA();
}

@Test
handleTest(){
    Mockito.lenient().when(bean1.method1(d)).thenReturn(c);
    sut.handle(d);
    Mockito.verify(bean1, times(1)).method1(any());
 }
}
```

I got error:

```
ClassATest > handleTest() FAILED
    Wanted but not invoked:
    bean1.method1(
        <any>
    );
```

Did I get anything wrong? Is there a way I can do this with Mockito?

Comment: I expected you to get a NPE as you failed to inject bean1 to sut. What is sut.bean1 when you execute the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I get anything wrong?

You mocked out `bean1` in the test but you didn't set it on the object `sut` - it has it's own internal `bean1` that is not a mock.

> Is there a way I can do this with Mockito?

You can pass the mock to the class to ensure it's the instance on which the method is invoked:

```
public class ClassA{

    @Autowired
    Bean1 bean1;

    // Constructor that explicitly sets the bean - for testing
    public ClassA(Bean1 theBean) {
       this.bean1 = theBean;
    }

    public ClassC handle(ClassD d) {

        ClassC c = bean1.method1(d);
        return methodA(c);
    }
}
```

Then your test passes the mock:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
ClassATest{
@Mock 
ClassD d;
@Mock
Bean1 bean1;

@Mock
ClassC c;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    sut = new ClassA(bean1); // PASS THE MOCK THROUGH
}

@Test
handleTest(){
    Mockito.lenient().when(bean1.method1(d)).thenReturn(c);
    sut.handle(d); // NOW WHEN THIS IS CALLED, IT'S USING A MOCK
    Mockito.verify(bean1, times(1)).method1(any());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `lenient()`. Lenient allows the method to be stubbed without verifying an invocation. That's why `verify()` is not checking anything. As for me, you need to remove `lenient()` and use regular `when()` method:

```
        when(bean1.method1(d)).thenReturn(c);
        sut.handle(d);
        verify(bean1, times(1)).method1(d);
```

and don't initialize ClassA. Just remove @beforeEach setUp and write this instead

```
@InjectMocks
ClassA sut;
```